# Automatic parentheses in `Show` instances

Tags: haskell

```
ghci> show (Left 3)
"Left 3"
ghci> show (Just 0)
"Just 0"
ghci> show (Just (Left 3))
"Just (Left 3)"
```

How does Haskell automatically put parentheses around nested constructor arguments?

Comment: The really short answer is [`showsPrec`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show), but that's not very useful by itself..

Comment: [`GHC.Show`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Show.html) offers the actual implementation of that `showsPrec` for `Maybe`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`showsPrec :: Int -> a -> ShowS`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:showsPrec) is the function used internally by `show` to consistently put parentheses around a term.

The `Int` parameter indicate the precedence of the outer context. If the precedence of the current constructor is greater than the precedence of the context, `showParen :: Bool -> ShowS -> ShowS` puts parentheses around the constructor. Here an example for a very basic AST :

```
data Exp = Exp :+: Exp
         | Exp :*: Exp

-- The precedence of operators in haskell should match with the AST shown
infixl 6 :+: 
infixl 7 :*:


mul_prec, add_prec :: Int
mul_prec = 7
add_prec = 6

instance Show Exp where
  showsPrec p (x :+: y) = showParen (p > add_prec) $ showsPrec (add_prec+1) x
                                                   . showString " :+: "
                                                   . showsPrec (add_prec+1) y
  showsPrec p (x :*: y) = showParen (p > mul_prec) $ showsPrec (mul_prec+1) x
                                                   . showString " :*: "
                                                   . showsPrec (mul_prec+1) y
  show t = showsPrec 0 t "" -- Default definition
```

`showsPrec`, `showString`, `showParen`, etc, act on difference lists (`ShowS = String -> String`), where the argument is a string appended to the result. Concatenation is done by composition, and conversion to `String` by application with an empty string.
The `show` implementation use `showsPrec` with the lowest precedence, the expression to print, and finally, the end of the string  `[]`.

Comment: Does it somehow increment the precedence parameter `p` each time you goes deeper into the tree? In your case, it doesn't look like `p` is getting incremented everytime however.

Comment: In the recursive call, `p` is set to the enclosing precedence +1.